# How to retrieve the key:true Firebase pattern in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new with firebase and I have some doubts that I've spend some time in try to find a solution:

This is my database looks:

```
user
   - l5tCeZmcZtXLITJugdtfHsK647s1
      email: "myemail@sample.com"
      name: "Bob"
   - userType
       guestType: 1
   - wedding
       Kke0cr5NUGEgg3rq_Mf: true
```

That I'm trying to do is how get the userType data and the wedding data, that is done with the pattern that said the firebase documentation key:true.

This is that I'm doing and I can see that I have all the collection data, but not idea how can I get the data for the labels userType and wedding:

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = ApplicationConfig.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
            Query queryFirebase = mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user").child(currentUser.getUid());

            queryFirebase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
```

My model;

```
public class User implements Serializable{
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private int guestType;
    private Wedding weeding;
    private String uid;


    public User() {

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(currentUser.getUid()).child("userType");

mDatabaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int guestType = (int) dataSnapshot.child("guestType").getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

In the same way you can retrieve the value of that id in the `wedding` node.

Hope it helps.